# How to prevent a 503 when using Wiremock.NET on Windows Server?

Tags: .net-core, windows-10, asp.net-core-webapi, windows-server-2016, wiremock

I developed integration tests for a .NET Core 3.1  Web API [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1). I have an external dependency (which is also REST Service). My tests are building, running and succeeding on my Windows 10 laptop. For stubbing the external dependency (as localhost), I use [WireMock.NET](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net). This is working fine. Wiremock returns the response (including status code) I configured it to return.

However, when running my tests on the company server (running Windows Server 2016), my tests are failing because the wiremock "server" (as localhost) returns a 503 all the time.

Do I need to configure something on my Server to ensure I can use WireMock.NET with localhost? It is really annoying. Everything works fine except when I run it on my server. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have any more logging available except the code 503? And do you use http or https?
If possible provide more details here, or create an issue here: https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/issues

Comment: I do not have more logging.

Comment: Maybe check the Log Entries via like here: https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/blob/master/src/WireMock.Net/Server/WireMockServer.LogEntries.cs#L44